# Identify specific airports using direction services

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a fare calculator using google maps direction services to calculate distance between 2 locations entered in the From-To textboxes. I have also assigned the autocomplete api to fetch list of locations to autocomplete while typing. This is working perfectly but now the requirement is changed. I want to identify if user has selected or enter any Airport as a From or To location. And based on that I want to calculate the fare. I have also got list of Airport names so I have to look into that if the entered address is from the list or not. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can get a place details and check if types field contains "airport". Add listener to intercept `place_changed` events of autocomplete and analyze the types field of [PlaceResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlaceResult) object. You can use [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function for this purpose.

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
    }

    if (place.types.includes("airport")) {
        //Implement your logic here
    }
});
```

You can see examples of place autocomplete in official documentation. E.g.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Please note that sometimes the user can select something that looks like airport name, but in reality is something different, for example a metro station that shares its name with airport. In this case you should apply a workaround described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928956/5140781

I hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting down vote. Just curious what is the reason. Would you mind explaining please.

Comment: No I didn't downvote it. In fact I already checked the Place type thing by printing the result object on console. That is fine, but I want to compare specific airport names with the one stored in my database and many times they are stored in slightly different spelling.